# What is the meaning of the .: in this linux statement?

Tags: command-line, java

Somebody helped me run a java program with the following (working) line of code. The zookeeper-3.4.5.jar exists in the working directory. What it is the meaning of the .: syntax here? Does that just mean current directory? I would have written this as `java -cp "zookeeper-3.4.5.jar"` but I'm not 100% sure this would do the same thing as the line below.

```
java -cp .:zookeeper-3.4.5.jar org.zookeeper.LsGroup
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` is the current directory. The `:` is the path separator, used to separate multiple paths in a single option/variable under *nix. This command line therefore adds both `.` and `zookeeper-3.4.5.jar` to the Java classpath.